# Почему ClickHouse на один и тот же запрос выдает разные результаты?

Tags: clickhouse

В ClickHouse создал такую таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
        id UUID DEFAULT generateUUIDv4(),
        id_task Int32,
        email String,
        checked Int32 DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE = MergeTree() order by id_task
```

После записал в нее данные (около 10млн строк).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь делаю такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id_task = 1 LIMIT 1
```

И каждый раз я получаю разный результат, но они как-то чередуются.

Почему такое поведение? Я хотел выбирать по 1 млн строк, то есть делать несколько выборок `LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 2000000` например.

Но теперь не уверен что во следующей выборке не попадутся результаты предыдущей...

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Задай порядок (`ORDER BY`). Лимит без сортировки не имеет смысла.

Comment: LIMIT без ORDER BY на любой СУБД выдаст что попало, clickhouse не исключение, о чём сказано в справке: https://clickhouse.com/docs/ru/sql-reference/statements/select/limit